# Как сделать так, что бы при перемещении картинки (элемента) вместе с ним двигалась точка

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: На картинке элемент цепи, создается с точками, но при перемещении точки остаются на месте]

Выручите хотя бы идеей

### Создание элемента на холсте

```
private void Image_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
     if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
     {
        var url = ((sender as Image).DataContext as Element).DisplayedImageShortUrl;
        var elm = new Element { DisplayedImage = url, Pos = new Point(100, 100) };
        elements.Add(elm);
        double X = elm.Pos.X;
        double Y = elm.Pos.Y;



        tochk = new Node { A = elm, X = X + 7, Y = Y + 32 };
        tochk1 = new Node { A = elm, X = X + 105, Y = Y + 32 };

        nodes.Add(tochk);
        nodes.Add(tochk1);



     }
  }
```

### Захват элемента мышкой для перемещения

```
private void Image_MouseDown_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
     if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
     {
        mousePress = e.GetPosition(this);
        var img = sender as Image;
        obj = img.DataContext as Element;
        img.CaptureMouse();
        e.Handled = true;




     }
  }
```

### Перемещение

```
private void Image_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
     if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && Keyboard.Modifiers != ModifierKeys.Shift)
     {
        var p = e.GetPosition(this);
        obj.MoveRef(p - mousePress);
        mousePress = p;
     }
  }
```

### Освобождение элемента

```
private void Image_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
     if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released)
     {
        var img = sender as Image;
        img.ReleaseMouseCapture();


     }
  }
```

### Класс создания узла

```
 public class Node
 {
   public Element A { get; set; }
   public double X { get; set; }
   public double Y { get; set; }

 }
```

### XML

```
 <ItemsControl x:Name="ic_nodes" Grid.Column="1">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Ellipse Width="5" Height="5" Fill="Black" MouseEnter="Ellipse_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Ellipse_MouseLeave">
                    <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform X="{Binding X}" Y="{Binding Y}"/>
                    </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                </Ellipse>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Сделайте точку частью элемента, который вы перемещаете

Comment: от есть лучше использовать usecontrol?

Comment: Да, это проще всего.